# How big can an object get before its core becomes degenerate?

Tags: planet, jupiter, mass, saturn, degenerate-matter

I am wondering, what is the most massive object we know of that does not have a degenerate core, and what is the least massive object that **does** have a degenerate code? We know that Jupiter has a core that is obviously degenerate. A quick Google search shows that Saturn is indeed degenerate, and is on the low end of electron-degeneracy. Are there any lesser-mass degenerate objects there, and what is the approximate boundary for electron-degenerate and non-degenerate matter?

Comment: Rob's answer here https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/15043/why-is-the-core-of-a-gas-giant-supported-by-electron-degeneracy-pressure-instead may help.

Comment: @JamesK Yes, it does, but just a little bit. I'll probably need more information than that though, perhaps a straightforward answer would do :)

Comment: A piece of metal is electron-degenerate matter. It really isn't clear how you can define a lower limit.