# Why do degenerate objects get hotter as more mass is added?

Tags: planet, temperature, brown-dwarf, degenerate-matter

After reading [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41580/how-big-can-an-object-get-before-its-core-becomes-degenerate), I decided to post a question about degeneracy. I've seen simulations on large, $15\text{+ }M_J$ objects that are accreting mass. They do not grow in radius, instead they shrink (that is something I know about degenerate objects). But why do they get hotter? I'm assuming it comes from the internal pressure, and at what mass does some sort of fusion occurs?

Comment: I have found this paper where they investigate the [Finite-temperature Extension for Cold Neutron Star](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ab08ea/meta#apjab08eaproc2)  taking degenerate matter into account. This could help you to answer how pressure and temperature work iniside a degenerate object.